# Change results in View by Radio button

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello again i coded this example to learn entity-framework.
[Build a CRUD Application with ASP.NET Core 3.0 & Entity Framework 3.0 Using Visual Studio 2019](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/build-crud-application-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework-visual-studio-2019.aspx)

now on the index.cshtml i added two radiobuttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdbAll" value="All" id="all-1" checked>
<label for="all-1">Show all</label>
<input type="radio" name="rdbOutOfStock" value="out" id="out-1">
<label for="out-1">Show out of stock</label>
```

if i check **All** i will show all entries.
if i check **out of stock** i will only show the products where **quantity == 0**

i know i can do something like that:

```
// GET: api/Products
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable>> GetProducts()
        {
          var products = _context.Products.AsQueryable();
          products = _context.Products.Where(i => i.AvailableQuantity == 0);
          return await products.ToListAsync();
        }
```

how can i call this function by checking the radio button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the radiobuttons in a form. Then you can post this form on changing the radiobutton like so:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
$(this).closest("form").submit();});
```

Comment: okay thank you! Now i can call the function. But how can i edit the shown data? i get always redirected but i will the data shown in the Index View

Comment: You can use an ajax post for that. Like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php/5004276#5004276